# When does cuda kernel go onto device's global Memory

Tags: cuda

I am developing a code in CUDA, but I am wondering at which time the kernel developed goes onto device's global Memory? 
Is it at compilation or during execution ?

Comment: What compilation are you asking about. CUDA supports JIT compilation, so compilation and execution can be the same thing

Comment: I think about an nvcc compilation from the main programm.

Answer (score 1):

If you compile a code using nvcc, that has no effect on any GPUs installed in the machine, and in fact may be done on a machine with no GPUs.

Any kernels to be loaded by a program will be loaded onto the GPU after that program begins execution.